# TabControl inside CustomControl loads with no selected tab item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I wrote a CustomControl that supports direct content. When I nest a TabControl in it, there's no tab item selected on launch. It happens only when using ItemsSource. Anyone know what's wrong?

[image]

**Sample implementation**

In MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:VM/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid Margin="20">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"/>
    <local:CustomControl1 Grid.Column="1">
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" />
    </local:CustomControl1>
</Grid>
```

VM.cs

```
class VM
{
    public List<int> Data { get; set; } = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
}
```

CustomControl1:

```
[ContentProperty("Content")]
public class CustomControl1 : Control
{
    static CustomControl1()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl1)));
    }

    public FrameworkElement Content
    {
        get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(CustomControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

In Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: In your Style for CustomControl1, try replacing your ContentPresenter with a ContentControl and manually set the Content property.

Comment: Good thought, but same behavior with ContentControl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time of poking around I've found a solution, but I am not sure of the exact reasons behind this behavior.

I've modified your example and compared the behavior when the `TabControl` was put inside a `ContentControl` and a `CustomControl1`. Predictably, the first tab in case of `ContentControl` was selected, but in case of `CustomControl1` it was not. After inspecting the [`ContentControl` source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ContentControl.cs) (in particular the [`ContentControl.OnContentChanged`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ContentControl.cs,1402c5e31cb441b9) method) we can see that what it does is it sets its content as its logical child.

I then confirmed that setting the `TabControl` as the `CustomControl1`'s logical child does the trick (but I'm not sure why, as I mentioned). So the minimal solution to your problem is to handle the logical relation between your control and its content in the property changed callback, e.g.:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Content",
        typeof(FrameworkElement),
        typeof(CustomControl1),
        new PropertyMetadata(null)
        {
            PropertyChangedCallback = OnContentChanged
        });

private static void OnContentChanged(DependencyObject d,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (CustomControl1)d;
    if (e.OldValue != null)
        control.RemoveLogicalChild(e.OldValue);
    if (e.NewValue != null)
        control.AddLogicalChild(e.NewValue);
}
```

Note though that this lacks some checks (e.g. if new value already does have a logical parent or the control is a part of a template), so you might want to simply copy the code from the referenced source, or fallback to deriving your control from `ContentControl` altogether.

Comment: Ah, nice! That does the trick. Didn't realize that for CustomControl I have to manage the logical tree (and TabControl depends on it). Time to read more. Thanks for digging!